# Crear un programa que cree diez conexiones Socket java

Tags: java, eclipse, socket

estoy tocando comunicaciones en red con java y eclipse. Quiero crear una pequeño programa que cree diez conexiones clientes y sean recibidas por una clase Servidor. Hasta ahora tengo estas dos clases.

```
import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;


public class ClienteSocketStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String mensajecliente = "Hola servidor";

         try {

         Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
         InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5569);

         clientSocket.connect(addr);




        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        // OutputStream is = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
         OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();




         } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
         }

    }


import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class ServeridorSocketStream {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();


 System.out.println("Creando el socket Servidor");


 InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5569);

 serverSocket.bind(addr);
 System.out.println("Realizando el bind al puerto 5559");
 Socket newSocket = serverSocket.accept();
 System.out.println("Objeto ha llegado");
 InputStream input = newSocket.getInputStream();
 OutputStream output = newSocket.getOutputStream();



 serverSocket.close();

 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y la duda/problema es?

Comment: Como hacer para crear 10 conexiones que se vayan conectando al servidor. No sé como implementarlo

Comment: Esto se suele hacer con hilos (threads) pero si solo quieres probar 10 conexiones sin nada mas de uso - hazlo en un bucle